# How to update the UI using bindings

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, stored-procedures, mvvm, datagrid

I have a DataGrid and two ListBoxes in my window. I am using Entity Framework to Connect to my SQL Server. Depending on the selections I make in the ListBoxes parameters will be passed to my stored procedure and data for my DataGrid will be retrieved. I was able to implement this functionality without using MVVM. I would like to know ways to implement this using MVVM. Please Help me out. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, MVVM is about separating the concerns of your code into the appropriate area. For example, talking to your database via EF should be done in the Model<sup>1</sup>. The ViewModel is responsible for holding the data, and for shaping or massaging it to make it more suitable for display (i.e. transforming enums to colors<sup>2</sup>, etc).

To implement your functionality in a MVVM way, you will need to use binding, and bind your viewmodel to your view:

```
<MyControl>
    <LayoutRoot>
        <ListBox ItemsSource={Binding MyItems} SelectedItem={Binding MySelection} />
    </LayoutRoot>
</MyControl>
```

in the code behind for the View:

```
public class MyControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        this.DataContext = new MyViewModel();
    }
}
```

and your ViewModel will look something like this:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyDataObject> MyItems 
    { 
        get { return _myItems; }
        set
        {
            _myItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyItems");
        } 
    }

    public MyDataObject MySelection { get; set; }

    public void DoSomethingWithDatabase()
    {
        Model.DoSomething(MySelection);
    }
}
```

This is just a VERY simple example to illustrate what is required if you do things the MVVM way (and I've deliberately missed out a bunch of stuff). To do a proper example and document all the essential bits you need to know would take at least a chapter in a book, so I'll refer you to a MSDN article for further reading: *[Implementing the Model-View-ViewModel Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg521153%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)*.

<sup>1</sup> And the Model may just be a stepping stone if you also implement SOA, the Model might just call a service which then talks to the database.
<sup>2</sup> This can also be done with [Converters](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html) in the View, but may not always be possible or practical in a converter.

Comment: Doing conversions in the view-model is really hard to do correctly. Most people who try end up hook up a property change notification betwee the model and view-model, which in turn ends up leaking memory.

Comment: I think you're conflating some of the responsibilities of the Model and VM.  And traditionally, tasks such as converting state into visual representations (`transforming enums to colors`) are *not* the job of the VM, but of the View (custom converters, DataTemplate selectors, etc).

Comment: @Will, hence footnote #2 - enums to colors was just an easily understandable example to use. I've seen plenty of cases where it was more appropriate to evaluate stuff in the VM instead of a converter (business rules, access to services), but I couldn't think of something simple and not contrived for my example.